# JavaScript - jQuery.Tabledit didn't work with specific url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was trying to intergrate jQuery.Tabledit (https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/) to my table. While it worked for one table, the other one didn't work. After lots of trial, I found out something weird when changing url.

Basic structure of my table:

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabledit.js"></script>
<table id="testing">
  <thead>
    <tr id="head">
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <th>1</th>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <th>2</th>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<?php var_dump($_SESSION); ?>
```

**tabledit.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testing').Tabledit({
        columns: {
            identifier: [0, 'id'],
            editable: [[1, 'Column 1'], [2, 'Column 2']]
        },

        onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('Success');
        },

        onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Fail');
        },

        onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
            console.log('onAjax');
            console.log(action);
            console.log(serialize);
        },

        hideIdentifier: false,
        url: '../../database/test.php',
    });
});
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'heya';
?>
```

Now, if I put the file **test.php** next to **tabledit.js** and change url code to

```
url: 'test.php',
```

, the session variable won't change, which means **test.php** isn't running at all.

If I put it to one folder above **tabledit.js** (ex: *project/table/tabledit.js* and *project/test.php*) and change url code to

```
url: '../test.php',
```

, it won't work either.
However, if I put it 2 folders above, like this:

```
url: '../../test.php',
```

, it works.
Same thing happens with

```
url: '../../database/test.php',
```

I had pull an all-nighter for this and still couldn't figure out why. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: try call test.php in browser with FQDN as regular url. eg. http://localhost/test.php .. if not working you have problem with exposing website. Absolute paths from your filesystem are prohibited. Or may be routing problem.

Comment: Change url to _'localhost/table/test.php'_, still didn't work. I didn't use any absolute paths, only relative paths. I use the latest XAMPP version for testing.